# Spigot server keeps erroring

Tags: java, minecraft

```
Could not load 'plugins\My_first_spigiot.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:160) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:144) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:383) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:874) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:642) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:758) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:743) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:387) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:356) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1007) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:846) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
```

Comment: Based on `Could not load 'plugins\My_first_spigiot.jar' in folder 'plugins'` it looks like your application expects folder structure like `plugins\plugins\My_first_spigiot.jar`. Since you are getting this error application configuration and file/folder structure don't match.

Comment: Unless you're developing a plugin for Minecraft—`My_first_spigiot.jar`?—this question might be a poor fit for Stack Overflow, which is about specific software development questions. This _might_ get a better response on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)—which is about software in general—or perhaps even [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)—which covers servers and network administration. If you are developing a plugin, you should offer some relevant configuration data, such as your `plugin.yml`, as suggested by the exception details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create **plugin.yml** file which contains plugin's name, author, version etc.

The simplest form of the plugin.yml should look something like this:

```
name: //the plugins name as it should appear in the plugin list /pl
version: //the plugin's version
author: //the author's name
main: //your main class were the onEnable and onDisable methods are. (Ex: org.spigotmc.tutorial.MyPluginName)
api-version: //the version of the API you want to use, required starting with 1.13
```

And i would like to share my plugin's plugin.yml
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZivG.png)

[here is a resource](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/)
[and another usefull resource](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-blank-spigot-plugin-in-intellij-idea/)